# mounting gcs bucket using gcsfuse in a startup script

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcsfuse

I would like to mount a bucket on my instance when it starts up. The command I use is:

```
gcsfuse --implicit-dirs mybucket /my/folder
```

This works when I do it manually ssh-ing into the instance. However, it fails within the startup script. There doesn't seem to be any errors in the log file but the created directory has `??????` for permissions, owner, etc. Using an Ubuntu 16.04 image.

Any ideas on what could be going on?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run the following command to mount my own bucket using a startup script with no ??????? for permission:

```
gcsfuse --implicit-dirs --dir-mode "777" -o allow_other -o nonempty MYBUCKET /MY/FOLDER
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for stopping the ?????? permissions issue.

First, be sure /etc/fuse.conf has user_allow_other uncommented

**Via the CLI:**

```
sudo nano /etc/fuse.conf
```

**Or, via a script:**

```
sudo echo "
user_allow_other" >> /etc/fuse.conf
```

Then for mounting the bucket, I've used this command in my script

```
sudo gcsfuse -o allow_other MYBUCKET /MY/FOLDER
```

You may want some other flags like `--implicit-dirs` for allowing the listing of directories within the bucket, so do your research and build upon this according to your needs.

Everything worked just fine with this method while using Ubuntu 22.04.